# what autocmd should i use to trigger a specific action

Tags: vim

I want vim to compile my latex file after i change it in the buffer
so i did :

```
au! InsertLeave *.tex :silent! update % | :silent! call Tex_CompileLatex()
```

However, it works only for leaving insert mode. I want the command to run whenever i make some changes to the buffer, e.g., after i "dd" a line, or replace a character by 'r', is there a way to do that?
also, "call Tex_CompileLatex()" takes some time to return, is there a way to run it in async way so i dont have to wait in vim?

I am not familiar with vimscript, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you make a motion seems a little bit too often, but you could accomplish it with `CursorMoved` or `CursorMovedI`. The asynchronous suggestion would require tweaking with vim-latex. If you wanted a simpler option that just ran a single LaTeX command on the current file you could use `:help system()` to make a system call in the background.

Comment: Update for every motion is too much, what i want is after every change made to the buffer. is motion also considered as a change to the buffer?

Comment: You could execute it every time you write the buffer, but the autocmd you want doesn't exist.